# How to unblock the InputStream read method in Android?

Tags: android

The InputStream.read() method blocks when connecting a o WiFi without internet. I am using android 2.3 and the library from Apache that is integrated in android. Also, I set the timeout of the request using setSoTimeout method, but no exception was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

check your timeout set, follow is a exmpale:

```
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, timeOutLimit);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, timeOutLimit);
    DefaultHttpClient mDefaultHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
    mDefaultHttpClient.execute(...)
```

also, the network connect need put in another thread to avoid block ui thread.